# ngx-charts-pie-chart angular5 library data format

Tags: typescript, angular5, ngx-charts

I'm using the library `ngx-charts` in my project.

The `onSelect` method returns an object with two attributes: `value` and `name`. Despite the fact that my list of type `any[]` is a list of objects with three attributes: `value`, `name` and `id`.

In the source code I found that the method only emits the `value` and `name` attributes.

```
PieGridSeriesComponent.prototype.onClick = function (data) {
        this.select.emit({
            name: this.data[0].data.name,
            value: this.data[0].data.value
        });
    };
```

Can I modify the source files or is there another way to alter what it returns in the onSelect method with the click event?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (and I think in effect TypeScript is too) is a prototype language. This means that you are in fact free to override the prototype of `onClick` with a function you define yourself without having to modify the source code.

That means that it should (probably) work to put the following somewhere in your own sourcecode:

```
PieGridSeriesComponent.prototype.onClick = function (data) {
    this.select.emit({
        name: this.data[0].data.name,
        value: this.data[0].data.value,
        id: this.data[0].data.id
    });
};
```